# Burnt oven insulation

Tags: wiring, insulation, oven

[image]

Is this safe to use after I change the power cord to a 4 prong? Just got this used stove/oven today.... previous owner said they just unplugged it yesterday but this has me nervous!

Comment: It still looks safe to use, no wires are melted, that is normal scorching from the oven

Answer (score 1):

Check the parts diagram and schematic. If this is the oven temperature sensor, some heat leakage and scorching is normal, and as long as enough insulation remains to keep it safe and the connectors are solid and the sensor is working you can get away with ignoring the scorch marks. "Broken as designed."

Comment: OTOH, if it is _not_ the oven temp sensor, does that mean this is cause for concern?

Comment: Possibly? If it's the oven temp sensor, heat being conducted back along it through the opening in the insulation is not atypical. If it isn't, you may want to figure out what it is and how it's getting hot. But from the look of it, it isn't a problem _yet_ in any case.